# When is it necessary to escape double quotes and other characters when inserting them into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

When is it necessary to escape double quotes and/or special characters when inserting into a text field in MySQL?

Assuming you have a text field that holds descriptions or articles that have double quotes and/or ampersands, is it necessary to escape them before writing them to the database table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL (nonstandardly) allows you to use double-quotes as delimiters of string literals:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE first_name = "Mel"
```

You would run into trouble if you interpolated content into your SQL string literal, and your content contained double-quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE description = "She said, "Murder"!"
```

This can be a simple accident, and this probably just causes a syntax error.  But attackers can also exploit this cleverly to make your queries do something you didn't intend.

```
UPDATE Accounts SET PASSWORD = "..." WHERE account_name = "Mel" OR "X"="X"
```

This could happen if the attacker claims their account name is `Mel" OR "X"="X` and this is called SQL Injection.

But if you escape the double-quotes in the content, you can defeat their mischief:

```
UPDATE Accounts SET PASSWORD = "..." WHERE account_name = "Mel\" OR \"X\"=\"X"
```

However, it's simpler to use query parameters, so you ensure that content is separate from SQL code, and can never result in unintended expressions:

```
UPDATE Accounts SET PASSWORD = ? WHERE account_name = ?
```

Parameters allow you to prepare a query with placeholders, and then provide dynamic content for each placeholder when you execute.  For example in PHP with PDO:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Accounts SET PASSWORD = ? WHERE account_name = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( array("...", "Mel") );
```

See my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) for lots more information.

Comment: Thank you Bill, and everyone else, for this thorough explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape them before storing them in the database, but if you are writing code to process user input **make sure** you read about and fully understand the risks of [SQL Injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or you are in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1):

- It would only be necessary to encode double quotes if you were adding a string into a string literal bounded by double-quotes. But, you shouldn't use double-quote-string-literals, because they're a weird non-standard MySQL syntax not supported by other databases.

  Instead, use single-quote-string-literals (eg `name='Mel'`), which are ANSI standard SQL and work everywhere. And then of course you need to escape single quotes in the value, not double quotes.
- The other main character you need to escape in MySQL string literals is `\`, because MySQL uses it as an escaping character. This is more non-standard behaviour and quite annoying.

Most webdev environments will give you an SQL-string-literal escaping function so you don't have to worry about which exact characters need escaping for inclusion in a query. For example, `mysql_real_escape_string` in PHP. However, as Bill mentioned, you are better off using parameterised queries where available, so you don't have to worry about SQL-escaping at all. Your text will jump straight into the database as raw strings without any intermediate escaping-unescaping step.

As for ampersands, they are not special in SQL string literals and should **not** be escaped when creating queries from strings. They're special in HTML, but you don't want HTML-encoded data in your database. Instead, use an HTML-escaping function (like `htmlspecialchars` in PHP) at the moment you insert a string into HTML content, and *not* before.

It is a common mistake to try to HTML-escape or ‘sanitise’ content in the input stage from a form submission or at the SQL-building stage. But this is an HTML output stage issue, which should only ever be tackled at the templating stage.