# Problem with $_POST, if isset() and mysql_fetch_assoc(): echo returns correct value, page source always returns else value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

This question started as a different thread, but after a lot of searching and narrowing down the problem it has changed quite significantly and as such I thought it may be relevant to start a new question an link back to the old one which is:

[Variable concatenated mysql query string runs fine in phpMyAdmin but not PHP in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627327/variable-concatenated-mysql-query-string-runs-fine-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-php-in-s)

I don't believe the description to be adequate anymore as the concatenation works fine.

It does seem that I am homing in on the problem. I have a simple form:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method = "post" name = "testform" action = "testgenxml.php" >
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "GFCheckbox">
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I then have a PHP function that checks if GFCheckbox is selected. If it is a certain string is passed to the $query value. If it isn't a different string is passed to the $query value. Here is the PHP function.

```
<?php

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
} 

$query = "";

if (isset($_POST['GFCheckbox'])) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM fdatav1 f INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID) WHERE (GFOption = "1")';

} else {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM fdatav1 f INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID)';
}

$connection = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo 'accname="' . parseToXML($row['accname']) . '" ';
    echo 'description="' . parseToXML($row['description']) . '" ';
    echo 'venue="' . parseToXML($row['venue']) . '" ';
    echo 'activity="' . parseToXML($row['activity']) . '" ';
  }
?>
```

When I select the checkbox, all the echo statements work perfectly and displays on screen all the records where GFOption = "1". But when I view the page source ALL the records are echoed there. **This is however specific to whatever I have in the else statement of the if condition.** If the checkbox is checked or unchecked, whatever I have in the else statement executes and if there is output it gets printed to the page source.

Another interesting thing is that if I hard code my if conditional statement to

```
if (true)
```

or

```
if (false)
```

the statements work exactly the way they should, and no weird page source printing happens.

If I do

```
var_dump(isset($_POST['GFCheckbox'])
```

I get the correct boolean values depending on if GFCheckbox is checked or not.

As you can see I am running in circles with this and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but something you should fix is to put `$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);` first in your `parseToXML`, or otherwise your `<` will turn into `&amp;lt;` (first replacing it with `&lt;` and then the `&` to `&amp;`).

Comment: Chances are, when you view the source, your browser is performing the request again, this time without the post parameter. Try a different browser.

Comment: @Roe: Spot on! I work mostly with Google Chrome, which is causing the problem it seems. Viewing the source for explorer and firefox are 100%. I still have to check and see if it is applicable to any case of else statement. Why would Chrome behave this way?

Comment: Also, I don't just think it is when I view the source. When I try to generate and xml file or echo to html output it causes problems as well.

Comment: Using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) with *ENT\_QUOTES* is probably better than using you own `parseToXML`. (See @roe’s comment for one reason.)

Comment: @Mario111 If you're using Chrome (like I do) then Developer Tools are essential (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $_GET or $_SESSION variables

The problem boiled down to Google Chrome. The issue I was having was a recognized bug in the software: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523 which I believe they are fixing in future editions of Google Chrome. I have just update mine and still does not work correctly.

I switched browsers to Firefox and Explorer and they rendered everthing correctly, even the XML output I was after.

Credit for this solution goes out to Roe for pointing out the potenital browser problem.

According to other posts using $_GET in stead of $_POST should work fine. $_SESSION variables should also do the trick.

Comment: I eventually ended up migrating to an AJAX solution, which made use of the POST method and it worked fine with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to still be checking isset() even though the question isn't whether it's set, the question is whether it's true or false.  PHP munges a lot of things when you check variables as booleans but isset() on a set variable *containing false* will still return true.

Try trading

```
if (isset($_POST['GFCheckbox']))
```

for

```
if ($_POST['GFCheckbox'])
```

and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. It works when viewing the page, he's asking what the problem is when viewing the source. You're correct in that it is a cleaner approach (it allows you to explicitly pass false), although I think most browsers will not include the parameter at all if it's unchecked.

Comment: I tried this option a couple of times, but unfortunately with the same result. I was blaming $_POST, but it seems its a Google Chrome browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in that code suggesting it would output all records when submitted with the box checked. It's probably the case that when you view the page source it's not sending the POST data, so you get all the records back.

If you have the Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox, you can verify this by using View Source -> View Generated Source, or alternatively with Firebug by inspecting the DOM. Failing that, try viewing source using a different web browser.

Comment: The problem is not really all the record being output, the problem is whatever the else statement is in my if conditional loop. If I had `echo "Whatever";` as my else statement, it would output whatever to my page source, regardless of the status of isset($_POST) condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jfcoder.com/test/checkbox.php

I have:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php 
print_r($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['GFCheckbox'])) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM fdatav1 f INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID) WHERE (GFOption = "1")';
} else {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM fdatav1 f INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID)';
}

echo "\n\nQUERY: $query";

?>
</pre>
  <form method = "post" name = "testform" action="" >
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "GFCheckbox">
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And it's acting as you're describing you want it to. Specifically, to use a WHERE clause if the checkbox is selected on the form submit.

So I don't think that it's the if statement. If you're using MySQL, <strike>your query looks wrong</strike>.

**NOTE**: I think <strike>most/all</strike> (see third note) relational database systems use the single quote syntax, but I'm not sure.

**SECOND NOTE**: I'm actually looking for the documentation to see if this is true. I've certainly always thought single quotes were required.

**THIRD NOTE**: This is actually NOT a problem with MySQL, see [When is it necessary to escape double quotes and other characters when inserting them into MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859707/when-is-it-necessary-to-escape-double-quotes-and-other-characters-when-inserting/3859777#3859777) for more information.

```
$query = '
SELECT * 
FROM fdatav1 f 
INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID) 
WHERE (GFOption = "1")
';
```

<strike>You need to use single quotes on the WHERE check, not double quotes</strike>. I would stick with single quotes for consistency, but apparently it's not required by MySQL.

```
$query = '
SELECT * 
FROM fdatav1 f 
INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID) 
WHERE GFOption = \'1\'
';
```

Or:

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
FROM fdatav1 f 
INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID) 
WHERE GFOption = '1'
";
```

<strike>I believe this is probably why your results are not working as expected.</strike>

Also, IMO you should not use `isset()` for the if but should check for the actual status report; ie...

```
if ($_POST['GFCheckbox'] == 'on') {
```

And I might do this a little differently (see comment):

```
$WHERE = "";

if (isset($_POST['GFCheckbox'])) {
    if ($WHERE == '') {
        $WHERE = "WHERE ";
    }
    $WHERE = "GFOption = '1'";
}

// This way it's easier to add options
// and edit your base query later.
// For instance, in case you add a 
// GROUP, LIMIT or ORDER BY.
if (isset($_POST['ABCCheckbox'])) {
    if ($WHERE == '') {
        $WHERE = "WHERE ";
    } else {
        $WHERE = " AND ";
    }
    $WHERE = "ABCOption = 'efg'";
}

$query = "
SELECT * 
FROM fdatav1 f 
INNER JOIN ddatav1 d USING(ID)
$WHERE
";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I originally had my comments the other way around, but switched to single outside quotes out of desperation for a solution. If I switch them back it works the same, will do so for good practice anyway. Thank for the suggestion on the base $query!

Comment: @Mario111 - Note I made a change, the original WHERE check was incorrect. I'm trying to determine if single quotes are required for string searches, as well.

Comment: @Mario111 - See my edit. Double quotes are allowed in MySQL after all.

Answer (score 0):

If checkbox not checked, then $_POST['GFCheckbox'] = 0, else $_POST['GFCheckbox'] = 1

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method = "post" name = "testform" action = "testgenxml.php" >
    <input type = "hidden" name="GFCheckbox" value= "0" >
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "GFCheckbox" value= "1" >
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```